# How to insert row in a table every time I insert a new row in the main table?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a Vb.net app that is connected to an Access 2010* Database, I have a table with personal information of many students and another table with multiple true/false fields for every course the student has succed.

The structure is something like this

Table `students`

```
 |Id_student | Name | Phone |
```

Table `finishedCourses`

```
| Id_stutent | chemistry | physics | maths |
```

How can I add a new row into `finishedCourses` table every time that I insert a new row into `students` table.

I don't know how add the rows with the same id in both tables.

I expect something like this

Table `students`

```
Id_student | Name | Phone
1234456    | abc  | 12432534645
```

Table `finishedCourses`

```
Id_stutent | chemistry | physics | maths
1234456    | false     | false   | false
```

The default values for Courses are `False'. Initial status of each course is incomplete.

Comment: User trigger in main table

Comment: Thanks! I solved it searching for trigger, I haven't used it before

Comment: I had shared sample code here, Check posted answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried to undestand what you want, you want to insert a initial values in finishedCourses when you insert a student information in table students, am I right?
I am not familiar with the Access database, I realized that the Access database may not have the trigger function, otherwise you can use the trigger to implement your requirement.
And in this problem, you can just write two insert SQLs to complete this with the same studentId, like below:

```
insert into students(id_101, 'Bob', '88089901');
insert into finishedCourses(id_101, false, false, false...);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server then you can use `trigger`. The sample code is as below, I have no idea about MS-Access

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[students] 
FOR INSERT
AS
DECLARE @Id_stutent int;

SELECT @Id_stutent=i.Id_student  FROM inserted i;   

INSERT  INTO finishedCourses
       (Id_stutent,chemistry,physics,maths) 
VALUES(@Id_stutent ,false , false , false ,false );
GO
```